# Usb otg not detected

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I checked my phone with USB otg checker and it shows that USB host support is detected. But when i plug in a otg cable it does not detect my flash drive. Any idea how to fix this.

Comment: Which device is it and which Android version are you using? It could be a problem with your OTG cable.

Comment: I am using gionee p3s and it has android 5.1 i have tried another otg cable before this new one and that did not work either

Comment: Have you tried with a powered hub. Some devices only provide host support with an external power supply.

Answer (score 1):

[Gadgets 360](http://m.gadgets.ndtv.com/gionee-pioneer-p3s-2981) review for P3S (see *connectivity under detailed specifications*) states OTG is **not supported**

Maybe the app you used returned a *false positive*

Comment: There appears to be conflicting evidence in the wild. For example, [this website](http://maktechblog.com/gionee-pioneer-p3s-launched-in-india-8313/) claims that the device comes with OTG support. There's even a [special USB OTG cable on sale](http://www.maxbhi.com/usb-otg-adapter-cable-for-gionee-pioneer-p3s.html), only for this phone.

Comment: @Firelord: I know that it doesn't work, checked *physically*, as I was helping my brother choose a low cost phone .  To back this picked the first internet hit supporting that. After you pointed out, checked  [OEM](http://gionee.co.in/smartphones/pioneer-P3S/) site, which doesn't talk of OTG at all, but highlights several features. IMO silence on this is *not* unintentional.  But the Cable on sale does raise a confusion, agreed

Comment: Even P3 , with a small cost difference didn't support as physically checked